# Really static HTML in React components

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a React app where I need to wrap a lot of components with raw HTML. They don't have state or pass props and I'm doing this so everything can be wrapped in a router so links can properly render certain components when clicked.

In other words, this...

```
<div class="foo">some text</div>
<div class="bar">some more text</div>
```

becomes this.

```
export const Foo = () => (
  <div className="foo">some text</div>
)

export const Bar = () => (
  <div className="bar">some more text</div>
)
```

And a file called `App.js` will then be this:

```
export const App = createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Foo />
        <Bar />
        <SomecomponentWithprops />
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

This does work and properly wraps all the stuff in `<Router />` the way I need to, but it doesn't seem right.  Just wondering if there's a best practice/more dynamic way?

Comment: Looks good. If you only want to display some HTML on some routes, this is the way to go. What is it you don't like about it?

Comment: @Tholle: thanks. I'm still ramping up on React and wasn't sure if this was an anti-pattern of some sort.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to go. If you only want to display certain content on certain routes, you have to split it up into different components, as you've done.